# Admissible search algorithms 15 puzzle, 8 way moves

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

Simple question:

Is the Euclidean distance admissible in a 15 puzzle if we assume a block can move in 8 directions (Horizontal, vertical, diagonal), at the same cost?

Answer (score 0):

No; `distance` needs to be a direct cognate to the number of steps in your state graph.  Consider the case of a single set of move choices: `up-left` and `up` are each a single step; Euclidean distance will tell you that `up-left` is more expensive.

This will expand to cases fatal to your optimal solutions.  For instance, moving three tiles in sequence across a main diagonal is only three steps, but Euclidean distance makes that to be more than four (3*sqrt(2)).